# Find all ideals in $\mathcal{A}\cap \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ that contain 30.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Find all ideals in $\mathcal{A}\cap \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ that contain 30.

so far, we found,

$\lt 2 \gt$ =$\lt 2, \alpha+1\gt^2$=$P^2_2$

$\lt 3 \gt$ = $\lt 3,\alpha - 1\gt \lt 3,\alpha + 1\gt$=$P_3 \hat P_3$

$\lt 5 \gt= \lt \alpha\gt^2$=$P_5^2$

And since there are no norms of 2 and 3, $\lt 2, \alpha+1\gt$, $\lt 3,\alpha - 1\gt$, $ \lt 3,\alpha + 1\gt$ are not principal.

we are stuck to find principal ideals.
for example , is $P_2P_3$ principal ideal?

Answer (score 2):

One knows that if $I$ is a non-zero ideal of norm $n=\mid{\cal O}_F/I\mid$ in the ring of integers ${\cal O}_F$ of a number field $F$, then it is principal if and only if it contains an element $x$ of norm $\pm n$. This element is then a generator.

Thus, since $P_p$ has norm $p$, in order to decide whether $P_2P_3$ (which has norm 6) is principal, you need to study the equation
$$
N(x)=N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2=\pm6
$$
for $x=a+b\sqrt{-5}\in{\cal O}_{\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-5}]}=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In the Dedekind ring $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ we have 
$$
30=(\sqrt{-5})^2(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}).
$$